# BigQuery select multiple key values

Tags: google-bigquery, key-value, firebase-analytics

With a custom event in Firebase exported to BigQuery, multiple key-value params can exist within it. I can't seem to figure out how to select more than just one of these using "standard SQL".

[image: How would I project both msg and succes values (string_value and int_value) into one record]

Comment: I understand the need for questions to be minimal, complete and verifiable for them to add value to Stackoverflow and its users. However, existing questions around the subject (which I looked for first naturally) were too large and complex. All I really wanted to know was how to extract multiple key-value params within a BigQuery dimension. Elliott Brossard reply worked beautifully for me so should for others as well.

Comment: Really appreciate the screenshot of the table schema / example data! Very easy to read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say that you wanted to select the `string_value` that corresponds with `firebase_event_origin` and the `int_value` associated with `firebase_screen_id` for all `control_reading` events. You could express the query as:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  (SELECT param.value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params) AS param
   WHERE param.key = 'firebase_event_origin') AS firebase_event_origin,
  (SELECT param.value.int_value
   FROM UNNEST(event_dim.params) AS param
   WHERE param.key = 'firebase_screen_id') AS firebase_screen_id
FROM `your_dataset.your_table_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170501' AND '20170503' AND
  event_dim.name = 'control_reading';
```

Comment: So they key is to use CROSS JOIN UNNEST on the dimension with subqueries. Works like a charm, thanks!